# The operator + is undefined for the arguement type(s) ChatColor, int

Tags: java, operator-keyword, minecraft, bukkit

I am coding a minecraft plugin. I'm having a small problem. So we have this:

```
int ok = Integer.parseInt(test) - 1;
lores.set(1, ChatColor.RED + ok);
```

Now the problem is, there's an error on the second line. The `+` operator is undefined for `ChatColor` and `int`. What the int `ok` does is, it subtracts one number from the minecraft lore of the item in their hand. Say their item is a stick with the lore `5 uses remaining!`. Now say they right click it. It will say 4 uses remaining. Everything seems to work great except for this little problem right here..

Comment: what is the input params of lores.set , int and int ?

Comment: You can not add 1 to an object of type ChatColor.

Comment: use `ChatColor.RED.toString() + String.valueOf(ok)`. Then it should work. The +-operator is only used for addition. When java goes through your code and finds two strings, it then concats your strings. If the first operand on your addition is a string, java converts to second operand to a string and concats them. Converting the ChatColor to a string solves the problem, but for the readability of your code you should convert `ok` to a string too.

Comment: Wow! Thank you for your help and all the information. Very useful and can really help me fix these issues in the future :)

Answer (score 4):

Your `+` operator gets two operands, a `ChatColor` object (`Object`) and `ok` (`int`). According to [The Java Language Specification §15.18](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18)

> If the type of either operand of a `+` operator is [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), then the operation is string concatenation.
>
> **Otherwise, the type of each of the operands of the `+` operator must be a type that is convertible ([§5.1.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8)) to a primitive numeric type, or a compile-time error occurs.**

Therefore, the only operations between `Object`s operable by the `+` operator will be:

- `String` + (anything, including `null`)
- When both operands are a subtype of `Number` or a primitive numeric value.

... Which is not the case here, and thus you get a compile-time error for invalid syntax: `ChatColor.RED + ok`

You can salvage this operation and concatenate the strings properly with either of:

```
ChatColor.RED.toString() + ok
or
ChatColor.RED + Integer.toString(ok)
```

Comment: @Jojodmo `"" + ChatColor.RED + ok` will work as well, as the first `"" + ChatColor.RED` will construct a String concatenation sequence. However this defines an empty string literal, which is a suboptimal operation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the parameter of `lore()` is a string.
So you need to do this:

```
lore.set(1, ChatColor.RED + "" + ok);
```

Now it should work.